# C# Pass lambda expression field into method and use field in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, parameters

How can I pass a field (via lambda expression) into a method and then use that field as part of a linq query?

I would like to call the method something like

```
IDictionary<string, string> stuff = foo(items, otherItems, otherItems => otherItems.FieldToUse)
```

I'm not sure how I would write the method, but I would want to use it sort of like the code below. I know I could use generics and pass the field name (via a string) into the method, but even then I don't know how I would use it in the linq query as follows. Also, I like using lambda, since I could just rename the field anytime I choose.

```
private IDictionary<string, string> foo<TModel>(IEnumerable<string> items, IEnumerable<TModel> otherItems, object FieldToUse)
    {
        //this will return a list of key value pairs of rowIDs and equipment
        IDictionary<string, string> x = (from o in otherItems
                                         join i in items on o.FieldToUse.ToString() equals i //joining on the equipment assetcode
                                         select new { rowID = o.RowID, item = i }).ToDictionary(k => k.rowID.ToString(), v => v.item);
        return x;
    }
```

Clarification: FieldToUse is a property or field of TModel

Comment: Question is not very clear. FieldsToUse is a type in otherItems ? When you are passing otherItems, there is no need to pass the field.

Comment: I don't always want to call the method using the same property, even if I am using the same type for TModel. Sometimes I want to use one property and sometimes another property

Comment: I think you want to use a selector. An example would be LINQs OrderBy method where you would call .OrderBy(obj => obj.Property); is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you need this to work against LINQ to Entities/SQL? Or is it enough to work against normal objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Func Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change the last parameter in method foo to

```
Func<TModel, String> FieldToUse
```

and in the LINQ query call the function

```
FieldToUse(o)
```

Here is the entire method foo

```
private IDictionary<string, string> foo<TModel>(IEnumerable<string> items,
  IEnumerable<TModel> otherItems,
  Func<TModel, String> FieldToUse)
{
  //this will return a list of key value pairs of rowIDs and equipment
  IDictionary<string, string> x = (from o in otherItems
                                   join i in items on FieldToUse(o) equals i //joining on the equipment assetcode
                                   select new { rowID = o.RowID, item = i })
                                   .ToDictionary(k => k.rowID.ToString(), v => v.item);
  return x;
}
```

This is how you can use it

```
public void DoStuff()
{
  string[] items = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
  List<Model> otherItems = new List<Model> { 
        new Model() { Field1 = "abc", Field2 = "xyz" }, 
        new Model() { Field1 = "abc", Field2 = "xyz" } };

  var result = foo<Model>(items, otherItems, a => a.Field2);
}

class Model 
{
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

You will have another problem though. The generic TModel does not have RowID. Perhaps provide a [generic where constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) for TModel.

The code then becomes

```
 private IDictionary<string, string> foo<TModel>(IEnumerable<string> items,
  IEnumerable<TModel> otherItems,
  Func<TModel, String> FieldToUse) where TModel : BaseModel
{
  //this will return a list of key value pairs of rowIDs and equipment
  IDictionary<string, string> x = (from o in otherItems
                                   join i in items on FieldToUse(o) equals i //joining on the equipment assetcode
                                   select new { rowID = o.RowID, item = i })
                                   .ToDictionary(k => k.rowID.ToString(), v => v.item);
  return x;
}

class BaseModel
{
  public int RowID { get; set; }
}
class Model : BaseModel
{
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```